# how to use angular-input-mask with a screen button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello I'm having a problem for the past 2 days using the angular-input-mask module
I'm trying to achieve the same effect I get when using my keyboard on a button on the screen.

```
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="money" ui-money-mask>
  <button ng-click="add('1')">1</button>
```

this is my script

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks'])

.controller('maskController', function($scope){

  $scope.add = function(num){

    $scope.money = num;

  }
})
```

This is my plunker that illustrated my problem.

[my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oszmUp6PlK0f7HhFkVN5?p=preview)

if I click on my input text and type 1. I get this result $0.01,

but if click on the number 1 I get this result in my input text $1.00.

Thanks in advance.

[angular input mask Module dependecy](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks)

Comment: The plunker link goes to input mask github page.

Comment: thanks for the information now is fixed.